# How to compute a variable that could not be separated into one side of the equation?

Tags: calculus, closed-form

For example: $\sin(x)=x+0.5$, how to compute the value of $x$ ?

Comment: In this case you can only approximate the solution numerically. Sadly it is not possible to solve all problems a closed form.

Comment: Usually, not at all, such equations usually require numerical methods. Sometimes, you can use the Lambert-W-function. Try the newton-method, it works not always, but often in practice. And usually, the convergence is quadratic.

Comment: thank you, is there a software that I can know the approximate value?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) can do most things. It's my go-to when I want to check if some sequence converges of some equation has a solution or some integral exists. It can't do _anything_, but most things it's decent at.

Comment: PARI/GP , for example

Comment: Yep, you can't just expect a transcendental equation like this to have a closed form solution. But in this case there's a particularly easy way to find a single *approximate* solution:  You know $\sin(x) \approx x -\frac{1}{6}x^3$ so $-3^{1/3}$ will be pretty close to the solution.

Comment: Also, someone mentioned wolfram alpha. It's literally as easy as typing $\sin(x) = x+1/2$ like so: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(x)+%3D+x%2B1%2F2

Comment: The title seems to suggest a different question than the main post. Could you clarify your question with an [edit]?

Comment: FWIW, this is a particular case of [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation), $M = E - e \sin E$, with $E=x, M=-0.5, e=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a general analytical method to solve problems like this. But a numerical method will rapidly yield a $x$ value that satisfies the equation. Rearrange the equation to ... and iterate this
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{n+1}= \sin x_n -0.5
\end{eqnarray*}
$ x \rightarrow -1.4973 \cdots$.

Comment: I used my calculator (OX-240) ... I put the formula $ (\sin ANS ) -0.5$ and then just pressed $=$ about 10 times.

Comment: Lol, same. That's how I do it, unless its really messy, then I write a program for it.

Comment: I've also found it benefical to add $mx$ to both sides, then divide by $1+m$.$$(m+1)x=\sin(x)+mx-0.5$$ $$x=\frac{\sin(x)+mx-0.5}{1+m}$$Choosing $m$ wisely will lead to much faster convergence then direct iterations.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I quite enjoy glacial convergence ... manically pressing the equal button to get the next decimal place! No seriously, that is very clever, introducing a parameter to increase the speed of convegence. Do you have a stategy for choosing its value for optimality ?

Comment: Ofc. Let $a$ be the solution in question. It is most optimal to have$$\frac d{dx}\sin(x)+mx-0.5\bigg|_{x=a}=0$$Play around with it and you get Newton's method I think.

Comment: As Claude Leibovici's answer shows, Newton's method converges nicely for this equation, even if the initial approximation isn't very close, although it'd be a little faster if you start with $x=-\sqrt[3]{3}$. Using arbitrary-precision arithmetic, I get $x=-1.4973003890958923146815215409476216475593964684572360$ in 6 loops.

Answer (score 2):

As already said, numerical methods are required. Plotting the function, you notice that the root is close to $x=-2$.

So, consider the function $$f(x)=x+\frac 12-\sin(x)$$

So, start Newton method using $x_0=-2$; the iterates will be given by
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n-\sin (x_n)+\frac{1}{2}}{1-\cos (x_n)}$$ leading to the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & -2.000000000 \\
 1 & -1.582880420 \\
 2 & -1.500917413 \\
 3 & -1.497307404 \\
 4 & -1.497300389
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you notice that the solution is really close to $-\frac \pi 2$, you could have very good approximations building the $[1,n]$ Padé approximants of the function around this point. Let us call $x^{(n)}$ the solution obtained.

They will be
$$x^{(1)}=\frac{12+3 \pi -\pi ^2}{2 \pi -14}\approx -1.4974020$$
$$x^{(2)}=\frac{21- \pi ^2}{4 \pi -20}\approx     -1.4973030$$
which seem to be acceptable.

Another thing you could do is to let $x=-\frac \pi 2+y$ making the equation to be
$$y+\cos (y)-\frac{\pi-1 }{2}=0$$ and use equivalent for $\cos(y)$. Thie approximation would lead to $$y^2-2 y+\pi -3=0 \implies y=1-\sqrt{4-\pi }\implies x=-\frac \pi 2+1-\sqrt{4-\pi }\approx -1.4972991$$